# Where is nvrtc_120_0.dl?

Tags: python, cuda, cuda-python

I ran "pip install pycuda” to run the sappy example in the cuda docs, but nvrtc_120_0.dll could not be found when running the code.

Clearly not part of the pip download.  Where can I find it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cuda\\_cuda\\cnvrtc.pyx", line 45, in cuda._cuda.cnvrtc.cuPythonInit
pywintypes.error: (126, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The specified module could not be found.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gtwpr\source\repos\PyExt3\PyExt3\PyExt3.py", line 150, in <module>
    err, prog = nvrtc.nvrtcCreateProgram(str.encode(saxpy), b"saxpy.cu", 0, [], [])
  File "cuda\\nvrtc.pyx", line 213, in cuda.nvrtc.nvrtcCreateProgram
  File "cuda\\cnvrtc.pyx", line 23, in cuda.cnvrtc.nvrtcCreateProgram
  File "cuda\\_cuda\\cnvrtc.pyx", line 196, in cuda._cuda.cnvrtc._nvrtcCreateProgram
  File "cuda\\_cuda\\cnvrtc.pyx", line 47, in cuda._cuda.cnvrtc.cuPythonInit
RuntimeError: Failed to LoadLibraryEx nvrtc64_120_0.dll
```

Comment: It's part of the NVIDIA CUDA tools.

Comment: Thanks, downloading latest.  Surprised a missing dependency is not mentioned in the pycuda download instructions.

Comment: Downloading cuda tools from nvidia and installing them resolved the issue.

Comment: What you are asking about is Cuda Python, not PyCUDA. They are not the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Install the cuda tools to resolve the missing library.